# When is delay too large for choosing synchronous calculation in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, latency

I am writing a node.js addon to perform some cryptographic computation, which may take about 1 μs – 20 μs.  Now I have a choice: implement this as a synchronous or as an asynchronous method (which does the computation on a background worker)?

It is obvious that network and I/O, which sometimes takes longer than a millisecond should be done asynchronously. Parsing JSON input is fast and should be done synchronously.

In my situation keeping the latency low is important, but optimizing away microseconds feels a lot like premature optimization.  So with this context in mind I would be interested to get your view on the question:

#### When using node.js, how long does a (synchronous) call have to block until you decide to run it asynchronously on a background thread?

Comment: Why should anything be synchronous in a single thread environment? There is no reason to imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is obvious that network and I/O, which sometimes takes longer than a millisecond should be done asynchronously. Parsing JSON input is fast and should be done synchronously.

This is not so obvious. There are asynchronous JSON parsers for Node. See:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-json-parse
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-parse-async

But it's true that at some point for a CPU intensive operation you need to use asynchronous operations. I would say that **any** CPU-intensive logic shouldn't be done in the main thread blocking the event loop and should be done in external processes or worker, or in a thread spawned from C++ to make it maximally transparent to the user.

See how it is done in `bcrypt` and `bcrypt-nodejs`:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs

If you can make your function work asynchronously (not only in a sense of using a callback but by actually not blocking the event loop) then I would recommend making at least two kinds of APIs - a function taking a callback and a function returning a promise (which can be one function in practice).

Currently with async/await you can use any function that returns a promise almost as if it were synchronous:

```
let x = await f();
let y = await g(x);
// ...
```

But there are some cases where you need a truly synchronous function, like if you want to have something that you can directly export from a module:

```
module.exports = f();
```

Here when the `f()` function is blocking there is no harm because the `require()` itself is blocking as well, and you should only use it once during startup. But if the function is asynchronous - by being declared with an `async` keyword and thus implicitly returning a promise, by explicitly returning a promise or by taking a callback, then you will not be able to export the value from a module and use it in certain ways.

So if you think that it makes sense that the return value of your function might be exported from modules then you may also need to provide a blocking, synchronous version.

Answer (score 1):

Why not implement this as a synchronous AND as an asynchronous method with 2 function like `cryptAsync()` and `cryptSync()` ? I think it's better and not difficult for you to do.

Comment: As an API designer I would hope to make this choice for the user. If one of the functions seems to be a better choice, I would like to omit the other one (to keep the API as simple as possible).

Comment: Then i think asynchronous is better